# How do I extend from a generic parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: generics, inheritance, typescript

I'm working on a pattern where an abstract parent class needs to inherit all the properties of the generic type supplied through its subclasses.

Here's a look at the constructor for the base class which gives a basic idea, and can also be [viewed on github](https://github.com/atrauzzi/anecdote-engine/blob/master/src/Drivers/AzureTables/Entity/Base.ts#L24-L32):

```
public constructor(data: T) {

    _.assign(this, _.omit(data, [
        "table",
        "id",
        "PartitionKey",
        "RowKey",
    ]));
}
```

---

What I'm looking for is some way to effectively express [this](https://github.com/atrauzzi/anecdote-engine/blob/master/src/Drivers/AzureTables/Entity/Base.ts#L16):

```
export abstract class Base<T extends EntityData> implements Storage.AbstractEntity & T {
...
```

---

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be supported currently and so I'm at a loss as to how I can make my base class extend its generic parameter such that any class that inherits from it [also receives the properties of the generic type it's encapsulating](https://github.com/atrauzzi/anecdote-engine/blob/master/src/Drivers/AzureTables/Entity/AuthorFact.ts#L7):

```
export class AuthorFact extends Base<Author> {

    public get RowKey() { return (this as any).id }
}
```

---

As you can see, I'm forced to remove `& T` from my base type and use `(this as any)` to suppress the compiler throwing an error.

What I'd like ultimately is for the type check on `.id` to succeed, as well as any other properties of `Author` to be available on the instance I'mm creating.

Answer (score 3):

Even with the latest commit that [allows classes and interfaces to derive from object types and intersections of object types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13604), extending classes from generic type parameter is still not allowed:

> An interface or class cannot extend a naked type parameter because it
>   is not possible to consistently verify there are no member name
>   conflicts in instantiations of the type.

But what is now allowed is crazy: you can build classes at run time and have them type-checked. (this requires `npm i typescript@next` which currently is 2.2):

```
import * as Azure from "azure";
import * as _ from "lodash";


export class Author {
    public id: string;
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public nativeIds: {[key: string]: string} = {};
    public posts: Post[];
    public created: Date;
}

export class Post {
   public constructor(
        public id: string,
        public author: Author,
        public title: string,
        public content: string,
        public authored: Date
    ) {
    }
}

type Constructor<T> = new () => T;
type DataConstructor<T, Data> = new (data: Data) => T;

function Base<T>(dataClass: Constructor<T>) {
    class Class extends (dataClass as Constructor<{}>) {
        public constructor(data: T) {
            super();
            _.assign(this, _.omit(data, [
                "table",
                "id",
                "PartitionKey",
                "RowKey",
            ]));
        }
        [property: string]: string | number | boolean | Date;
    }
    return Class as Constructor<T & Class>;
}

function Fact<T, Data>(superClass: DataConstructor<T, Data>) {
    class Class extends (superClass as DataConstructor<{}, Data>) {
        public get PartitionKey() { return "fact" }
    }
    return Class as DataConstructor<T & Class, Data>
}

function Identifiable<T, Data>(superClass: DataConstructor<T, Data>) {
    class Class extends (superClass as DataConstructor<{}, Data>) {
        public id: string;
        public get RowKey() { return this.id }
    }
    return Class as DataConstructor<T & Class, Data>
}

function IdentifiableDataFact<Data>(dataClass: Constructor<Data>) {
    return Identifiable(Fact(Base(dataClass)));
}


class AuthorFact extends IdentifiableDataFact(Author) {
}

// let's init some data
let author = new Author();
author.id = 'a';
author.firstName = 'z';
author.lastName = 'q';


// let's see what we've got    
let authorFact = new AuthorFact(author); // it has a constructor that takes Author

let e: Azure.Entity = authorFact; // it's structurally compatible with Azure.Entity

// it has PartitionKey
console.log(authorFact.PartitionKey);         // prints fact

// it has some properties that were copied over by Base constructor (except id)
console.log(authorFact.firstName);     // prints z

// it has index signature (check with --noImplicitAny)
const ps = ['lastName', 'nativeIds'];
ps.forEach(p => console.log(authorFact[p]));  // prints q {}

// and it has RowKey but it's undefined here (this might not be what you want)
// because id is explicitly omitted from being copied in Base constructor
console.log(authorFact.RowKey);    // undefined
```

It turns out that you can't do that with abstract classes, but I think structural types still allow you to do what you want here.

Comment: Is there any chance I might be able to use mapped types?  Also, why are you using functions instead of classes to wrap some things?

Comment: No idea about mapped types. Functions are necessary because you can't do `type T = A & B; class C extends T {}` because for `extends`, T has to be a value as well as a type - you get `error TS2693: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`. Function that returns class type is the only way to do that.

Comment: I'm going to keep your answer in mind as it seems like one workable approach. I just want to verify that newer language features haven't landed that might yield a less...circuitous...solution ;)