# Typescript/Loopback Related Models

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs, typescript-typings

I'm trying to define related models such as the [HasMany](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasMany-relations.html) relationship within the [@types/loopback definitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/loopback)

I have defined an interface for HasMany as it is implemented:

```
  interface IHasMany {
        /**
         * Create a target model instance
         * @param {Object} targetModelData The target model data
         * @param {Function} callback The callback function
         */
        // HasMany.prototype.create = function(targetModelData, options, cb)
        create<T = any>(targetModelData: any, callback?: (err: Error, instance: T) => void): Promise<T> | void;

(snip ... other functions findById, exists, updateById, destroyById omitted for bevity)
```

The Role model has the following build-in relations (as defined in the loopback module):

```
"relations": {
    "principals": {
        "type": "hasMany",
        "model": "RoleMapping",
        "foreignKey": "roleId"
    }
}
```

In Typescript, this function would be used as follows:

```
await createdRole.principals.create({
    principalType: loopback.RoleMapping.USER, 
    principalId: createdUser.id
});
```

(NOTE: loopback.RoleMapping.USER is a constant in an upcoming PR I'll be submitting to DT)

So now, I need to attach this interface to the Role model, and have it reference the RoleMapping model.

```
  class Role extends PersistedModel {
        static OWNER: string;
        static RELATED: string;
        static AUTHENTICATED: string;
        static UNAUTHENTICATED: string;
        static EVERYONE: string;

        /** HasMany RoleMappings */
        static async principals = ????
```

Any guidance on the next steps?  Seems like I need to extend IHasMany to be RoleMapping specific (such as IHaveManyRoleMappings) -- possibly using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841855/how-do-i-extend-from-a-generic-parameter-in-typescript), then have principals be something like:

```
static async principals = class RoleMappings implements IHasManyRoleMappings {};
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, for anyone else coming across this issue, here's the key:

In the interface, make it a generic interface with this `<T>`:

```
  interface HasMany<T> {
        /**
         * Find a related item by foreign key
         * @param {*} id The foreign key
         * @param {Object} [options] Options
         * @param {instanceCallback} callback
         */
        // HasMany.prototype.findById = function(fkId, options, cb)
        findById<T = any>(id: any, options?: any, callback?: (err: Error, instance: T) => void): Promise<T> | void;
(snip ... other functions findById, exists, updateById, destroyById omitted for bevity)
```

Next, you simply include this in your interface/class as follows:

```
  class Role extends PersistedModel {
        static OWNER: string;
        static RELATED: string;
        static AUTHENTICATED: string;
        static UNAUTHENTICATED: string;
        static EVERYONE: string;

        /** HasMany RoleMappings */
        //  createdRole.principals.create({principalType: loopback.RoleMapping.USER, principalId: createdUser.id});
        principals: HasMany<RoleMapping>;
```

Now it's easy to use as follows:

```
await createdRole.principals.create({ 
    principalType: loopback.RoleMapping.USER, 
    principalId: createdUser.id
})
```

Comment: This is actually brilliant. I was defining get, find, count on each class