# Extends from a generic parameter in Typescript

Tags: typescript, oop, generics

I am trying to extends a class dynamically. At instantiation of this class, I would like to specify the class it is deriving, not at definition.

Why I need this: I have an interface that contains thousands of fields. I automatically generate implementation classes of this interface depending on the need (one can returns undefined on field member the other raise an exception).

I want a concrete class which will extends those class in generic way:

```js
// This interface is automatically generated
interface AbstractData {
    field?: string;
    // thousands of other fields.
}

// This class is automatically generated
class BaseData implements AbstractData {
    field?: string;
    // thousands of other fields.
}

// This class is automatically generated
class CheckedData implements AbstractData {
    private underlying_field?: string;
    public get field(): string {
        if (this.underlying_field === undefined) {
            throw new Error('field is undefined');
        }
        return this.underlying_field;
    }
    public set field(v: string) { this.underlying_field = v; }
    // thousands of other accessors.
}

class ConcreteData<T> extends T { // Can't do this
    public constructor(data: AbstractData) {
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, data);
    }

    public get additionalField() { return `field: ${this.field}`; }
}

const data = { field: 'value' };
const b = new ConcreteData<BaseData>(data);
console.log(b.field, b.additionalField);
```

There are multiple questions in the same vein but no answer seems to fit my need:

- [extending interface with generic in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652179/extending-interface-with-generic-in-typescript)
- [Typescript generics extending class and interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273714/typescript-generics-extending-class-and-interface)
- [Extending a generic parameter in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988188/extending-a-generic-parameter-in-typescript)
- [How do I extend from a generic parameter in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841855/how-do-i-extend-from-a-generic-parameter-in-typescript)

The last one got me scratching my head for a while but it does not fit. The "intermediate" class is not specified at instantiation, it still would require to write special versions of `ConcreteData` for each specialization of the interface. Meaning, if you were to add a third way of accessing the data, you would need a third specialization for `ConcreteData`. But I intend to have many different type of `ConcreteData`-like classes against `AbstractData` which makes this solution impractical.

Is there a way to make a class inherit from a another class based on parameters provided at instantiation and still keep the benefits of the typing system of Typescript?